# Why can't a reference an old object when creating a new one

Tags: javascript

In the Chrome dev console, if I do this:

```
obj1 = Object({"a":"b"})
```

I can do this:

```
obj1.a
// -> "b"
```

But I can't do this:

```
Object({obj1.a:"c"})
// -> throws "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ."
```

Why?

Comment: You don't need `Object`. And object in JS is simply `{}`. The second syntax is invalid. `var obj={a:'b'}; obj.a='c'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax error is because the object key cannot be directly evaluated in that notation. You'd have to do something like this:

```
obj2 = {};
obj2[obj1.a] = 'c';
obj2[obj1.a];
```

For more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

What is going on at a deeper level is the `{ }` syntax is using an object initializer to construct the object. The property name of the syntax requires `a name, a number, or a string literal`. Evaluation of another object does not meet this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Because thats awkward syntax. Obj1.c inside your last line wony be evaluated as a variable. It only accepts property names. Obj1.c is not a valid name for a property